# How to write the data from a HashMap into a file in Sorted order with Streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, java-io, filewriter

I can output sorted entries from a `HashMap` like this:

```
public static void sortAverageTime(HashMap<String, Integer> noSortedMap) {
    noSortedMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + "ms"));
}
```

But now I need to *write* the entries into a *file*. I'm doing this:

```
try {
    File file = new File("newfile.txt");
    if (!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
    averageTime.entrySet().stream()
                          .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
                          .forEach(x -> fw.write(x + "ms"));
    fw.write("---" + currentDate + "\n");
    fw.close();
}
```

An **error** is displayed:

> Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException.

How can I output sorted entries from a `HashMap` to a *file*?

Comment: first sort the map and then iterate  to write in file

Comment: That error has to do with the file operations you are trying to do could result in an IOException and you need to handle it. It is either handled by doing a try-catch (or try-with-resources) or by throwing the exception to the calling method. Which of them depends on how you want to handle the exception.

Comment: Also seeing that you actually that you have your code in a try, you may just want to add a catch to that try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing *IO-operations* like writing to a file is *not a good idea* because exception-handling plumbing code completely defeats the **readability of lambda expressions**.

The primary reason why function programming was introduced in Java is to provide the *better way* of *structuring the code*, loops are always more **performant** than *sequential streams*.

I suggest to address this problem in two separate steps: first, prepare the data and then write it into a file.

Preparing the data will entail:

- *sorting* the map contents;
- converting each entry into a `String` and adding a time-unit of `"ms"`;
- collecting the sorted data into a **list**.

The **first step** might look like this:

```
public static List<String> getSortedData(Map<String, Integer> averageTime) {
    return averageTime.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .map(entry -> String.format("%s %d %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), "ms"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Writing to a file** (for better performance `FileWriter` is wrapped into a `BufferedWriter`)

```
public static void sortAverageTime(Map<String, Integer> averageTime,
                                   String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();

    List<String> sortedData = getSortedData(averageTime);
    sortedData.add("---" + LocalDate.now()); // replacement for fw.write("---" + currentDate + "\n")
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
        for (String next: sortedData) {
            writer.write(next);
            writer.newLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And with **Java NIO** the second step could be simplified to:

```
public static void sortAverageTime(Map<String, Integer> averageTime,
                                   String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();

    List<String> sortedData = getSortedData(averageTime);
    sortedData.add("---" + LocalDate.now());
    try {
        Files.write(file.toPath(), sortedData, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*A couple of important notes*:

- **Never** close resources inside the `try` block, if exception occur the resource will get never released. For that can either use [**try with resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (which is a preferred way), explicitly invoke `close()` in the `finally` block.
- Usage of the `forEach()` operation is [**discouraged by the documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) in situations when there's an alternative way to achieve the same result. So the approach of writing to the file from stream is **bad** on all counts:

  **-** it decries *readability*;

  **-** it makes your method *less narrow-focused* and *harder to test*;

  **-** it is not *aligned with the documentation*.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the exception while writing **`fw.write(x + "ms");`** to file see below code . **FileWriter write** function  thow **IO exception** which you didn't handle.

```
try {
            File file = new File("newfile.txt");
            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            noSortedMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
                    .forEach(x -> {
                        try {
                            fw.write(x + "ms");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
            fw.write("---" + new Date() + "\n");
            fw.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception occur emsg= "+w.getMessage());
        }
```